# access to property of another class from NSOperation object

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, concurrency

Dear community.
I have NSOperation subclass with property:

```
@property(readwrite, getter=isCancelled) BOOL cancelled;
```

from where i was create object of subclass NSObject (from init):

```
database = [[[MySQLIXC alloc] initWithQuene:iQuene andCarrier:startForCarrier withState:cancelled] retain];
```

In this custom object i try to declare local iVar:

```
@interface MySQLIXC :  NSObject {
       BOOL _currentQueueStatus;
```

In init:

```
- (id)initWithQuene:(NSUInteger)quene andCarrier:(NSString *)carrierName withState:(BOOL)currentQueueStatus;
    _currentQueueStatus = currentQueueStatus;
```

But currentQueueStatus allways null.
Can somebody suggest a problem location?

Comment: Where, specifically, are you trying to declare `_currentQueueStatus`? Please show the code you added it to.

Comment: Tnx for u time, i was update question

Comment: You still haven't shown the code you're declaring it in. Please show that code.

Answer (score 1):

1) you should avoid re-declaring implemented subclass interface for your additions (e.g. `-[NSOperation isCancelled]` exists)

2) it is very unusual to start with two retain counts:

```
database = [[MySQLIXC alloc] initWithQuene:iQuene andCarrier:startForCarrier withState:cancelled];
[otherThingThatHoldsAReference setDatabase:database];
```

instead of:

`database = [[[MySQLIXC alloc] initWithQuene:iQuene andCarrier:startForCarrier withState:cancelled] retain];`

3) `_currentQueueStatus` is not `null` it's a `BOOL`, which is a `signed char`. it should be `0` (`NO`) or `1` (`YES`).

4) what is `currentQueueStatus`? more code would help you receive more specific answers.

EDIT: updated for clarification in response to comments

```
/* things would look different if you subclass MONOperation */
@interface MONOperation : NSOperation
{
@private
    MySQLIXC * sqlIxc;
    BOOL didCancelDatabaseRequest;
}

/*
do not use isCancelled for your name - NSOperation declares this method, and
its implementation is well defined. this would override the implementation
and likely cause runtime errors.

specifically, NSOperation/NSOperationQueue uses cancel and isCancelled in its
interface and state. if you must cancel, then call cancel from cancelDatabaseRequest.
you may override cancel, but call [super cancel] in your implementation.
*/
@property (readonly) BOOL didCancelDatabaseRequest;
@property (retain) MySQLIXC * sqlIxc;

@end

@implementation MONOperation

/* ... */

- (BOOL)didCancelDatabaseRequest
{
    return didCancelDatabaseRequest;
}

- (void)cancelDatabaseRequest /* in this example, there is no sense making cancelDatabaseRequest publicly visible */
{
/* for example */
    assert(self.sqlIxc);
    self.sqlIxc = nil;
    didCancelDatabaseRequest = YES;
    [self cancel]; /* do this rather than overriding NSOperation's cancellation interfaces in your subclass */
}

- (void)main
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    assert(self.sqlIxc);
    self.sqlIxc.doStuff;
    if (self.sqlIxc.didTimeout || self.sqlIxc.couldNotAccessFile) {
        [self cancelDatabaseRequest];
    }
    else {
    /* use the result */
    }
    [pool release];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thx for u answer: 1)  this is a new declaration, i hope it's correct @property(readwrite) BOOL cancelled; 2) my MySQLIXC *database just declared in @interface of subclass NSOperation. I have to declare other property (retain or assign?) for MySQLIXC *database2 and make [self setDatabase2:database] in u example? 3)  I understand that i can't be null, but i see it in NSLog(@"MYSQL: queue status:%@",_currentQueueStatus); 4) i was update question regarding it.

Comment: you're welcome 1) it replaces NSOperation's implementation - you must choose another name, such as `isDatabaseRequestCancelled`. this is a crash waiting to happen (NSOperation/NSOperationQueue implementations will become very confused) 2) retain it 3) your NSLog call should generate a compiler warning. if not, turn up the compiler warnings - passing a signed char as an objc object via %@ format specifier is a bad access waiting to happen.

Comment: 1) this declaration in NSOperation subclass i mean. i still have to choose another name? if it true, i can't set this attributes (started,cancelled,executing,paused,finished). if u mean subclass, i try to send there current state of property cancelled. In class, i have another declaration in init for this state:  _currentQueueStatus = currentQueueStatus; as u see on my edited example.

Comment: i've added an example to the response - hope that clears things up

Comment: Dear Justin. Tnx for useful example, but in this example u do cancel from main operation queue subclass. But i need read state isCancelled from my subclass and make something there (cancel transactions e.t.c) can u re-write according this?

Comment: this is a hypothetical use which avoids the error. it should be enough to implement it correctly. just extend the class appropriate for your needs, using the info i've provided. specifically, you probably want to override `cancel` to accomplish this. in your implementation, call `[super cancel]`, and do your cleanup. since this is your extension to NSOperation's implementation, be aware that `cancel` may be called from outside of your subclass -- you'll have to decide what's best for your implementation to support cancellation appropriately for your uses.

Comment: Let me clear it. Currently i have: NSOperationClass -> createdObjectOfNSObjectClass. If i want to read property isCancelled, i can call from createdObjectOfNSObjectClass [super isCancelled]? or if i want to cancel operation from createdObjectOfNSObjectClass i call [super cancel]?

Comment: overriding `cancel` is fine - but you must call `[super cancel]` in your implementation of `cancel`. do *not* call `[super cancel]` outside of your implementation of `cancel`. do *not* override `isCancelled` -- add a method with a unique name (as i've described). you should not need to call `[super isCancelled]`. technically, yes, you *could* override `isCancelled` and implement it without issue, but it is a bad design which can be avoided easily. i'm also not convinced you understand the contract well enough to implement it correctly. cancel/isCancelled defines a very specific behavior.

Comment: but how i can connect current state of isCancel in method with unique name? it necessary because createdObjectOfNSObjectClass have to read a state isCancel of NSOperationClass sometimes to check if it necessary to return.

Comment: you're dealing with (and exposing in the interface) two distinct forms of cancellation. calling `[self cancel]` in `cancelDatabaseRequest` is one option. you can also call `isDatabaseRequestCancelled` once you've determined the NSOperation instance responds to the message -- if you need to distinguish cancellation type/reason.

Comment: it's method will looking like -(BOOL)isDatabaseRequestCancelled { return isCancelled; }? how i can calling it from MySQLIXC? [MONOperation isDatabaseRequestCancelled] ?